# JQuery Response Type is string instead of document object

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-11

I have some trouble with internet explorer 11 handling the response object of a post request with jquery 1.7.

```
loader.request = jQuery
            .post("/gateway-portal-war/prediction", {
                action : "index",
                matchcode : this.customerMatchCode,
                timespan : timespan
            })
            .done(
                    function(data) {
                        loader.displayData(data
                                .getElementsByTagName("response")[0]);
                        document.getElementById('loader_'
                                + loader.customerMatchCode).style.display = "none";
                    });
```

in firefox/chrome the object is treated as a html document element which works fine for further processing, getting the response from document and so on.

[image]

the problem here is that the response in IE is a xml within a string like its shown below:

```
"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n\n<response>\n ...</response>\n"
```

i tried to fix that one by converting response to activeXObject

```
xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
xmlDoc.async = false;

//xmlDoc.load(data);
xmlDoc.loadXML(data);
```

but after debugging i found out that nearly everything in the ActiveXObject was not initialized or is null, which produces some errors afterwards

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the dataType in the ajax call;

```
    .post("/gateway-portal-war/prediction", {
            action : "index",
            dataType: "xml", //here
            matchcode : this.customerMatchCode,
            timespan : timespan
        })
```

And jQuery parses you automatically. Maybe IE11 is unable to parse if you don't define it.

Comment: thank you, for your help, your dataType fix and a fix to the load of the xml data did the job (xmlDoc.loadXML(data) instead of xmlDoc.loadXML(data)) - i'll edit that above